# How pass a angular model as a parameter to a javascript function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I pass a parameter from an angular to a javascript function?

If I try to `collectDataById({{model.Id}})` I get an error. My model is being updated after the page load for first time. This what I want to have but with {{model.Id}} inside the JS function is having an error.

```
 <tr data-ng-repeat="model in models">
     <td class="text-center table-darker">{{model.name}}</td>
     <td class="text-center">{{model.Id}}</td>
     <td><a href="" data-ng-click="collectDataById({{model.Id}})">Get Data</a></td>
 </tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ng-click` is an Angular directive, so omit the `{{}}`

```
<a href="" data-ng-click="collectDataById(model.Id)">
```